# Найти количество вхождений подстроки в строку java stream api

Tags: java, строки, java-stream, substring

Задали задачу на собеседовании: найти количество вхождений подстроки в строку с использованием `java stream api`.

Пример:

```java
String str = "Multiple findme classes and nested " +
        "static findme classes are supported, " +
        "Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data " +
        "to output will cause the test findmecases " +
        "to failfindme";

String substr = "findme";
```

Результат:

```
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стримом тоже можно решить эффективно (в данном случае без создания дополнительных массивов/коллекций и без использования регулярных выражений), хотя и не очень наглядно, по сути это завуалированный for.

(преимущества стрима будут видны если задание изменится и надо будет делать еще какие нибудь дополнительные операции)

```
long count = IntStream.iterate(
            str.indexOf(substr), // начинаем с первого вхождения
            i -> i != -1, // пока не получим негативный ответ
            i -> str.indexOf(substr, i + 1)) // ищем следующее вхождение
        .count(); // считаем вхождения

System.out.println(count);
```

Код будет работать и на больших строках,
а также с пересекающимися подстроками,
например

```
String str = "aaaaaaa";
String substr = "aa";
```

ЗЫ: Java9+

Answer (score 2):

**Решение 1:** используем фильтр.

```java
String str = "Multiple findme classes and nested " +
        "static findme classes are supported, " +
        "Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data " +
        "to output will cause the test findmecases " +
        "to failfindme";

String substr = "findme";

long count =
    // разделяем исходную строку по пробельным
    // символам на массив слов и обходим его
    Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s"))
        // фильтруем стрим по словам,
        // содержащим подстроку
        .filter(word -> word.contains(substr))
        // выводим количество слов
        .count();

System.out.println(count); // 4
```

Такой алгоритм не будет работать для тех случаев, когда в каком-либо слове искомая подстрока встречается два раза или более.

---

**Решение 2:** должно работать во всех случаях, в т. ч. для двух и более вхождений подстроки в одно слово, также для цифр, спецсимволов и т. д.

```java
long count =
    // добавляем к исходной строке какой-либо
    // символ и делим ее по подстроке.
    // Обходим массив частей исходной строки
    Arrays.stream((str + " ").split(substr))
        // Считаем части
        .count();

System.out.println(count - 1); // 4
```

---

**Решение 3:** упрощенный вариант, без стримов.

```java
int count = (str + " ").split(substr).length;

System.out.println(count - 1); // 4
```

Comment: не будет работать например если substr=".", потому что String.split принимает regex, т.е. в этих случаях его надо эскейпить.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Multiple findme classes and nested " +
            "static findme classes are supported, " +
            "Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data " +
            "to output will cause the test findmecases " +
            "to failfindme";

    String substr = "findme";

    Long count = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
            .filter(s -> s.contains(substr))
            .count();
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: А если будет слово `findmefindme`?

Comment: Для конкретной задачи - конкретный ответ, если будет, надо будет изменить код.