# Ошибки при попытке удалить нужный подтекст из текста java

Tags: java

Код работает, пока не столкнется с двумя одинаковыми подтекстами в самом тексте. Суть кода в том, что он должен удалить все найденные подтексты и вывести отфильтрованный.
В данном случае очистить текст от всех "qwerty"
Если ввести qwertyqwerty...text...qwerty выдает ошибки.
Я пробовал создавать другие дополнительные StringBuffer которые уже изменял, не помогло

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("qwertyqwerty");//ошибка
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("qwerty", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    int shift = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        text.delete(matcher.start() - shift, matcher.end() - shift);
        shift+= matcher.end() - matcher.start();
        }
    System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154817/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-java-stream-api/1154822#1154822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"выдает ошибки" - ???

---

Уберите весь код, связанный с `shift`.

Comment: извините, недосмотрел. Теперь все работает, спасибо вам

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("qwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyqwertyQWERTYtext : hello worldqwerty");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("qwerty", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int p = 0;
        while (matcher.find(p)) {
            p = matcher.start();
            text.delete(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

//text : hello world

Process finished with exit code 0